# How can be remove a value from jmeter response using regular expression

Tags: jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

Response is **{"d":"14049,171681785,347225778"}** and I want to extract the value 171681785 from response
Can somebody help me how to write regular expression to extract 171681785 from the above response?

Answer (score 0):

Since 14049 can change, i can advise you to use JSON Extractor indeed. After getting the value of d with $.d, you can use this code in JSR223 Post Proccesor to get the value in the middle.

```
String[] array = vars.get("yourVariableName").split(",");
vars.put("theValueYouWant", array[1]);
```